# Does anyone have a working example of Omnipay and Sagepay Server or Sagepay Direct (with 3D Secure)?

Tags: opayo, omnipay

I'm struggling to get either to work and Omnipay doesn't come with much documentation. I've successfully used it for other payment gateways but not with Sagepay. I'm trying to integrate it into CodeIgniter but can work from examples in other frameworks - I'm getting desperate!

Comment: Just found out the simulator is no longer supported which is what I was using for testing. I don't know yet if that is the cause of my problems as now have to setup a partner account for testing but thought I'd update this in case anyone else comes across this in the meantime.

Comment: There is also a thread regarding Sagepay protocols 3 and Omnipay here https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay/issues/19

Comment: This thread has put me on the right track: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/255

Comment: I'll try and put up an example when I have some working code to save others struggling when there is currently a lack of documentation/examples for Omnipay/Sagepay

Comment: As promised I have shared my code in answer to this question. It may have not been a great question (hence I'm guessing the reason for the downvote), but currently there is little documentation for Omnipay and no example for Sagepay.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some great help on github (see comments in my original post for the thread link), I now have some workable code which I will share here in case it helps someone else in the future.

```
<?php 

use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class PaymentGateway  {

    //live details
    private $live_vendor = 'xxx';
    //test details
    private $test_vendor= 'xxx';

    //payment settings
    private $testMode = true;
    private $api_vendor = '';
    private $gateway = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //setup api details for test or live
        if ($this->testMode) :
            $this->api_vendor = $this->test_vendor;
        else :
            $this->api_vendor = $this->live_vendor;
        endif;

        //initialise the payment gateway
        $this->gateway = Omnipay::create('SagePay_Server');
        $this->gateway->setVendor($this->api_vendor);
        $this->gateway->setTestMode($this->testMode);



    }


    public function initiate()
    {

        //get order details
        $orderNo = customFunctionToGetOrderNo(); //get the order number from your system however you store and retrieve it

        $params = array(
            'description'=> 'Online order',
            'currency'=> 'GBP',
            'transactionId'=> $orderNo,
            'amount'=> customFunctionToGetOrderTotal($orderNo)
        );


        $customer = customFunctionToGetCustomerDetails($orderNo);

        $params['returnUrl'] = '/payment-gateway-process/' . $orderNo .  '/'; //this is the Sagepay NotificationURL

        $params['card'] = array(
            'firstName' => $customer['billing_firstname'],
            'lastName' => $customer['billing_lastname'],
            'email' => $customer['billing_email'],
            'billingAddress1' => $customer['billing_address1'],
            'billingAddress2' => $customer['billing_address2'],
            'billingCity' => $customer['billing_town'],
            'billingPostcode' => $customer['billing_postcode'],
            'billingCountry' => $customer['billing_country'],
            'billingPhone' => $customer['billing_telephone'],
            'shippingAddress1' => $customer['delivery_address1'],
            'shippingAddress2' => $customer['delivery_address2'],
            'shippingCity' => $customer['delivery_town'],
            'shippingPostcode' => $customer['delivery_postcode'],
            'shippingCountry' => $customer['delivery_country']
        );


        try {
            $response = $this->gateway->purchase($params)->send();


            if ($response->isSuccessful()) :

                //not using this part

            elseif ($response->isRedirect()) :

                $reference = $response->getTransactionReference();
                customFunctionToSaveTransactionReference($orderNo, $reference);
                $response->redirect();

            else :
                //do something with an error
                echo $response->getMessage();

            endif;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            //do something with this if an error has occurred
            echo 'Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.';
        }



    }


    public function processPayment($orderNo)
    {

        $params = array(
            'description'=> 'Online order',
            'currency'=> 'GBP',
            'transactionId'=> $orderNo,
            'amount'=> customFunctionToGetOrderTotal($orderNo)
        );

        $customer = customFunctionToGetCustomerDetails($orderNo);


        $transactionReference = customFunctionToGetTransactionReference($orderNo);


        try {
            $response = $this->gateway->completePurchase(array(
                'transactionId' => $orderNo,
                'transactionReference' => $transactionReference,
            ))->send();

            customFunctionToSaveStatus($orderNo, array('payment_status' => $response->getStatus()));
            customFunctionToSaveMessage($orderNo, array('gateway_response' => $response->getMessage()));

            //encrypt it to stop anyone being able to view other orders
            $encodeOrderNo = customFunctionToEncodeOrderNo($orderNo);
            $response->confirm('/payment-gateway-response/' . $encodeOrderNo);

        } catch(InvalidResponseException $e) {
            // Send "INVALID" response back to SagePay.
            $request = $this->gateway->completePurchase(array());
            $response = new \Omnipay\SagePay\Message\ServerCompleteAuthorizeResponse($request, array());

            customFunctionToSaveStatus($orderNo, array('payment_status' => $response->getStatus()));
            customFunctionToSaveMessage($orderNo, array('gateway_response' => $response->getMessage()));

            redirect('/payment-error-response/');
        }



    }


    public function paymentResponse($encodedOrderNo)
    {
        $orderNo = customFunctionToDecode($encodedOrderNo);
        $sessionOrderNo = customFunctionToGetOrderNo(); 
        if ($orderNo != $sessionOrderNo) :
            //do something here as someone is trying to fake a successful order
        endif;
        $status = customFunctionToGetOrderStatus($orderNo);

        switch(strtolower($status)) :
            case 'ok' :
                customFunctionToHandleSuccess($orderNo);
            break;

            case 'rejected' :
            case 'notauthed' :
                //do something to handle failed payments
            break;

            case 'error' :
               //do something to handle errors

            break;

            default:

                //do something if it ever reaches here

        endswitch;


    }

 }
```

Comment: I see the order number is encrypted in the return URL. Another way is to not provide any parameters on that URL, but to rely on the orderNo having been saved to the session before the notify handler is called. The "redirect" on error is also wrong - no redirect will work here. You must call `$response->error('your url', 'your optional message');` instead, and that will return the URL to SagePay who will then send the user to that URL for you.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a talk last night about this, and have put the working demo scripts on github here:

https://github.com/academe/OmniPay-SagePay-Demo

SagePay Direct is a one-off action - OmniPay sends the transaction details and gets an immediate response.

SagePay Server involves a redirect of the user to the SagePay website to authorise the transaction using their card details. This API uses a notify message, where SagePay will call your application directly with the authorisation results. This happens outside of the user's session, and so requires the transaction to be stored in the database so it can be shared between the two transactions.

All this is in the scripts linked above. `authorize.php` will do the authorisation. Edit that to use `SagePay\Direct` or `SagePay\Server` to see how it works. The notification handler for `SagePay\Server` is `sagepay-confirm.php` and that ultimately sends the user to `final.php` where the result can be read from the transaction stored in the database.

The scripts are all commented and should make sense, but feel free to ask more questions about them here or in the issue tracker of that github repository.

I've not tried `SagePay\Direct` with 3D-Secure though. The scripts may need some modification to support that, assuming that combination is *a thing*.